# SSIS Expression to append file extension

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I'll get a Full filepath(FilePath and FileName) from a variable (`@[User::V_FullPath]`)  as `C:/Users/ABCD/Documents/Development/SampleFile.txt`

I have a file with the same name but with `.xlsx` (`SampleFile.xlsx`) in another folder(A) that I want to copy to another folder(B)

To get just the filename I'm using the expression:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::V_FullPath],37,47)
```

How can I append `.xlsx` to the above expression
My goal is to get `SampleFile.xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just replace `.txt` with `.xlsx`?

```
REPLACE( @[User::V_FullPath]),".txt",".xlsx")
```

This will result in the following value:

> C:/Users/ABCD/Documents/Development/SampleFile.xlsx

If you need only the filename `Sample.xlsx`, you can use `TOKEN` and `TOKENCOUNT` functions as follows:

```
TOKEN(TOKEN(@[User::V_FullPath],"/", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::V_FullPath],"/")), ".", 1) +".xlsx"
```

Expression result:

> Sample.xlsx

---

##### Similar questions:

- [How do I extract file name from a path within an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880370/how-do-i-extract-file-name-from-a-path-within-an-ssis-package/56044097#56044097)

Comment: Thank you @Hadi for you solution